# Nodejs promise all not running as expected

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise

I have a series of promises which I have chained in `testCard`. This method takes a `stripe` card number, get the token from stripe and then talks to a third party API which tries to perform purchases with that card. 
I need to run `testCard` by looping through an array of card numbers. To do this I have a `controller` object with a method `testAllCards` which takes the array of numbers. The array is stored in a config file.

I then run the code from the command line with `node cli.js testAllCards`.

However when I run it, I get `testAllCards has been run` before all most promises have resolved.
I am obviously missing something here, but can't seem to figure out what it is.

**cli.js**

```
const testAllCards = () => {
  return controller.testAllCards(config.get('CARD_NUMBERS'))
    .then((obj) => {
      console.log('testAllCards has been run');
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log('testCards has been run with an error!');
      const _err = new ErrHandler(e, eTopicName, eSnsSubject);
      _err.handle()
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Error has been sent with success to sns');
        });
    });
};

switch(process.argv[2]) {
  case 'testAllCards':
    testAllCards();
    break;
  default:
    console.log('Please run with `testAllCards`');
```

**controller.js**

```
//Tests response from API for different cards
const testCard = (cardNum) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const expMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    const expYear = new Date().getFullYear() + 2;
    const cardObj = {
      cardNum: cardNum,
      expMonth: expMonth,
      expYear: expYear
    };
    let apiCardItem = '';
    return testRequestToApi('getStripeToken', 200, 299, cardObj)
      .then((cardItem) => {
        return testRequestToApi('postNewCard', 200, 299, JSON.parse(cardItem.body));
      })
      .then((apiCard) => {
        apiCardItem = apiCard.body;
        try {
          apiCardItem = JSON.parse(apiCardItem);
        } catch(e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
        return testRequestToApi('sampleAddToCart', 200, 299);
      })
      .then(() => {
        return testRequestToApi('useFailingStripeCards', 400, 499, apiCardItem.id);
      })
      .then(() => {
        return testRequestToApi('deleteCard', 200, 299, apiCardItem.id);
      })
      .then(() => {
        resolve();
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        reject(e);
      });
  });
};

//Loops through the card numbers and runs the test command against them
Controller.testAllCards = (cardsArray) => {
  const items = cardsArray.map((cardNum) => {
    return testCard(cardNum);
  });
  return Promise.all(items);
};

module.exports = Controller;
```

**test-request-to-api.js**

```
'use strict';

const checkStatus = require('./../utils/status-code-checker');
const formHeaders = require('./../utils/form-req-headers');
const request     = require('request');
const expObj = {};

//@requestType {string} - defines which headers and function name to use
//@item {object} - defines item that is being used
expObj.testRequestToApi = (requestType, lowerLimit, upperLimit, item) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reqOps = formHeaders[requestType](item);
    request(reqOps, (err, response, body) => {
      if (err) {
        const badRequest = {
          ErrorMessage: err,
          FuncName: requestType,
          InternalError: true
        };
        return reject(badRequest);
      }
      if (!checkStatus.checkRangeStatusCode(response.statusCode, lowerLimit, upperLimit)) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(body, null, 2));
        // Set a bad Status error object
        let badStatus = {
          StatusCode: response.statusCode,
          ErrorMessage: body,
          FuncName: requestType,
          InternalError: false
        };
        return reject(badStatus);
      }
      // console.log(response.headers);
      // console.log(body);
      const resObj = {
        headers: response.headers,
        body: body
      };
      // console.log(`******** ${requestType} *********`);
      // console.log(resObj);
      // console.log('----------------------------------');
      return resolve(resObj);
    });
  });
};

module.exports = expObj;
```

Comment: This is the [explicit promise construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). This is the first thing you should fix. `new Promise()` is only ever necessary when you are promisifying a callback-based API, which you aren't. In the same go you should switch from `request` to [`request-promise`](https://github.com/request/request-promise).

Comment: The next thing you should fix is your reliance on a outer-scope variable (`apiCardItem` in this case) to contain asynchronous state. The return values from your promise handlers ought to contain operation results.

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak. Your pointers helped solve the problem.

Comment: Can you post an answer the summarizes the cause of the error and what you did to fix it, with reference to the sample code from your question?

Answer (score 2):

Understanding that `new Promise()` is used only ever necessary when promisifying a callback based API, changing to `request-promise` and returning my promises in `cli.js` solved my issue. The execution flow was correctly maintained in this manner.

Changes to the following files are as followed:
**cli.js**

```
const testAllCards = () => {
  return controller.testAllCards(config.get('CARD_NUMBERS'))
    .then((obj) => {
      console.log('testAllCards has been run');
    })
    .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e)
      console.log('testCards has been run with an error!');
      const _err = new ErrHandler(e, eTopicName, eSnsSubject);
      return _err.handle()
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Error has been sent with success to sns');
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log('Failed to publish to sns');
          console.log(e);
        });
    });
};
```

**test-request-to-api**

```
'use strict';

const checkStatus = require('./../utils/status-code-checker');
const formHeaders = require('./../utils/form-req-headers');
const rqp         = require('request-promise');
const expObj = {};

//@requestType {string} - defines which headers and function name to use
//@item {object} - defines item that is being used
expObj.testRequestToApi = (requestType, lowerLimit, upperLimit, item) => {
  const reqOps = formHeaders[requestType](item);
  return rqp(reqOps)
    .then((response) => {
      if (!checkStatus.checkRangeStatusCode(response.statusCode, lowerLimit, upperLimit)) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.body, null, 2));
        // Set a bad Status error object
        return {
          StatusCode: response.statusCode,
          ErrorMessage: response.body,
          FuncName: requestType,
          InternalError: false
        };
      }
      // console.log(response.headers);
      // console.log(response.body);
      const resObj = {
        headers: response.headers,
        body: response.body,
        previousItem: item
      };
      // console.log(`******** ${requestType} *********`);
      // console.log(resObj);
      // console.log('----------------------------------');
      return resObj;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      return {
        ErrorMessage: e,
        FuncName: requestType,
        InternalError: true
      };
    });
};

module.exports = expObj;
```

**controller.js**

```
//Tests response from API for different cards
Controller.testCard = (cardNum) => {
  const expMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
  const expYear = new Date().getFullYear() + 2;
  const cardObj = {
    cardNum: cardNum,
    expMonth: expMonth,
    expYear: expYear
  };
  let apiCardItem = '';
  return testRequestToApi('getStripeToken', 200, 299, cardObj)
    .then((cardItem) => {
      return testRequestToApi('postNewCard', 200, 299, JSON.parse(cardItem.body));
    })
    .then((apiCard) => {
      apiCardItem = apiCard.body;
      try {
        apiCardItem = JSON.parse(apiCardItem);
      } catch(e) {
        console.log('Already a JSON object -----> Moving on');
      }
      return testRequestToApi('sampleAddToCart', 200, 299);
    })
    .then(() => testRequestToApi('useFailingStripeCards', 400, 499, apiCardItem.id))
    .then(() => testRequestToApi('deleteCard', 200, 299, apiCardItem.id));
};

//Loops through the card numbers and runs the test command against them
Controller.testAllCards = (cardsArray) => {
  return Promise.all(cardsArray.map((cardNum) => {
    return Controller.testCard(cardNum);
  }));
};

module.exports = Controller;
```

Comment: Good answer. I had virtually the same code ready, but got somewhat lost in details that are of more philosophical nature, so I figured pointing out the two main issues I saw would be enough for you to figure it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your "testCard" function (controller.js)

```js
//Tests response from API for different cards
const testCard = (cardNum) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let apiCardItem = '';
    const expDate = new Date();
    const cardObj = {
      cardNum:  cardNum,
      expMonth: expDate.getMonth() + 1,
      expYear:  expDate.getFullYear() + 2
    };
    
    testRequestToApi('getStripeToken', 200, 299, cardObj)

      .then((cardItem) => testRequestToApi('postNewCard', 200, 299, JSON.parse(cardItem.body)))

      .then((apiCard) => {
        apiCardItem = apiCard.body;
        try {
          apiCardItem = JSON.parse(apiCardItem);
        } catch(e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
        return testRequestToApi('sampleAddToCart', 200, 299);
      })

      .then(() => testRequestToApi('useFailingStripeCards', 400, 499, apiCardItem.id))

      .then(() => testRequestToApi('deleteCard', 200, 299, apiCardItem.id))

      .then(resolve)

      .catch(reject);
  });
};
```

And your "testRequestToApi" (test-request-to-api.js)

```js
expObj.testRequestToApi = (requestType, lowerLimit, upperLimit, item) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reqOps = formHeaders[requestType](item);

    request(reqOps, (err, response, body) => {
      let badStatus  = {};
      let badRequest = {};
      let resObj     = {};

      if (err) {
        badRequest = {
          ErrorMessage:  err,
          FuncName:      requestType,
          InternalError: true
        };

        reject(badRequest);
        return false;
      }
      
      if (!checkStatus.checkRangeStatusCode(response.statusCode, lowerLimit, upperLimit)) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(body, null, 2));
        // Set a bad Status error object
        badStatus = {
          StatusCode:    response.statusCode,
          ErrorMessage:  body,
          FuncName:      requestType,
          InternalError: false
        };

        reject(badStatus);
        return false;
      }

      resObj = {
        headers: response.headers,
        body:    body
      };

      resolve(resObj);
    });
  });
};
```

I think the problem is when you return from a promise before a resolve/reject is getting called.

Also check that in nested promises you can pass resolve/reject to .then/catch for brevity.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Same issue. `'testAllCards has been run'` is still logged before the logs on other functions